# tensorflow constant with variable size

Tags: tensorflow

I have a variable batch size, so all of my inputs are of the form

```
tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, ...)
```

to accept the variable batch sizes. However, how might you create a constant value with variable batch size? The issue is with this line:

```
log_probs = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
```

It is giving me an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I'm sure it is possible to initialize a constant tensor with variable batch size, how might I do so?

I've also tried the following:

```
tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=[-1, 1])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Too many elements provided. Needed at most -1, but received 1
```

Comment: You can't -- "tf.constant" constructs the array explicitly so it needs to know the dimensions. However, many tensorflow ops support broadcasting, so perhaps you can use that instead?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#constant) has fixed size and value at graph construction time, so it probably isn't the right op for your application.

If you are trying to create a tensor with a dynamic size and the same (constant) value for every element, you can use [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#fill) and [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) to create an appropriately-shaped tensor. For example, to create a tensor `t` that has the same shape as `input` and the value `0.5` everywhere:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, ...))

# `tf.shape(input)` takes the dynamic shape of `input`.
t = tf.fill(tf.shape(input), 0.5)
```

As [Yaroslav mentions in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853483/tensorflow-constant-with-variable-size#comment59374756_35853483), you may also be able to use [(NumPy-style) broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to avoid materializing a tensor with dynamic shape. For example, if `input` has shape `(None, 32)` and `t` has shape `(1, 32)` then computing `tf.mul(input, t)` will broadcast `t` on the first dimension to match the shape of `input`.

Comment: What if I want the shape to be dependent on just the batch size? Say I have an input tensor of shape `(batch_size, height, width, num_channels)` where batch_size is None. I want to create a tensor of shape `(batch_size)` filled with value `height`.

Comment: You can use the same method: `height_vector = tf.fill(tf.shape(input_tensor)[0:1], tf.shape(input_tensor)[1])`.

Comment: This works just fine too: `height_vector = tf.fill([tf.shape(input_tensor)[0], tf.shape(input_tensor)[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to do something using `log_probs`. For example, you want to do power operation on a tensor `v` and a constant `log_probs`. And you want the shape of log_probs to vary with the shape of v.

```
v = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1)
log_probs = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
result = tf.pow(v, log_probs)
```

However, you cannot construct the constant `log_probs`. While, firstly, you can construct tf.constant just with shape =[1] `log_prob = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])`. Then use `tf.map_fn()` to do pow operation for each element of v.

```
v = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1)
log_prob = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1])
result = tf.map_fn(lambda ele : tf.pow(ele, log_prob), v)
```