# tensorflow: how create an const tensor the same shape as a placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a place holder for input:

```
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, n_outputs))
```

Now I want to create a constant the same shape the Y:

```
w = Y.get_shape()
zero = tf.constant(np.zeros(w), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Error return:

```
__index__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer in another post
[tensorflow-constant-with-variable-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853483/tensorflow-constant-with-variable-size)

```
zero = tf.fill(tf.shape(Y), 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill your tensor with zeros or ones, you can use the `tf.zeros_like` and `tf.ones_like` methods as shorthand for `tf.fill`.

```
a = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

a_zeros = tf.zeros_like(a)
a_zeros
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just build your constant with the same shape as your placeholder, something like this should work.

```
zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32, shape(none, n_outputs))
```

I think because the placeholder has not been feed any data that is why you are getting an error

Comment: I tried your idea: zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32, shape = (None, n_outputs)), here is the error "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'".

Comment: get rid of the none maybe

Comment: just have shape(n_outputs)