# Tensorflow (Python): How to append a scalar to each row in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have a 2-d tensor with the first dimension being dynamic, how can I append a scalar value to the end of each row?

So if I feed [[1,2], [3,4]] to a tensor, I want to make it [[1,2,5], [3,4,5]].

Example (doesn't work):

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])
b = tf.concat([tf.constant(5), a], axis=1)
```

This gives me:
ValueError: Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) for 'concat_3' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [], [?,2], [].

I assume this needs some combination of tf.stack, tf.tile, and tf.shape, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853483/tensorflow-constant-with-variable-size), and especially the comments under it, could give you a hint.

Answer (score 3):

IMO padding is the easiest way here:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])
b = tf.pad(a, [[0, 0], [0, 1]], constant_values=5)
```

will append a `5`-column.

Documentation: [`tf.pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

- Expand the dimensions on the scalar tensor that you want to append to make it rank 2.
- Use [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) to repeat the rows.
- Concatenate both tensors along the last axis.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])
c = tf.constant(5)[None, None]  # Expand dims. Shape=(1, 1)
c = tf.tile(c, [tf.shape(a)[0], 1])  # Repeat rows. Shape=(tf.shape(a)[0], 1)
b = tf.concat([a, c], axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(b, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by rvinas answer, I came up with a simpler solution :

```py
constants = tf.fill((tf.shape(tensors)[0], 1), 5.0) # create the constant column vector
tensors = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([tensors, constants])
```